# Logstash Input plugin for loading data from REST endpoint into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, elk

I am looking for a way to load rest service data into Elasticsearch using Logstash. I would like to know is there any way to achieve this?

I tried using `http-poller input plugin` , seems `http-poller` requires a scheduler. But I just need to hit the endpoint only once (i.e after I start the logstash) then load the data. I don't want to continuously poll the data.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit what the exact purpose of this is? for one time sending data you could look into the API of elasticsearch itself and just create a simple bash or python script that does this.

Comment: @youryDW what's  you are telling is definitely a way of doing the one time loaf